# What params do I pass to grep to return only file names?

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm trying to use grep to find a specific piece of text in a bunch of files on my web server. No problem, except that it returns way more information than I want! Ideally it would just return a list of files, and if the text exists in more than one place in the file it would only list the file name once.

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
grep -ir essay_ "mysite"
```

to do a case-insensitive recursive search for the word essay_ in all directories of my site. What it returns is something like this:

```
mysite/dot/contest_declaration.php:$questions = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM dot_essay WHERE active = 1 order by display_order asc");
mysite/dot/contest_declaration.php:     $db->query("DELETE FROM dot_essay_xref WHERE entry_id = $svar_entry_id");
mysite/dot/contest_declaration.php:     $id = $question->essay_id;
mysite/dot/contest_declaration.php:     $answer = ${"essay_$id"};
shoppermarketexpo/dot/print_declaration.php:        $questions = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM dot_essay WHERE active = 1");
```

What I'd like to get back is:

```
mysite/dot/contest_declaration.php
mysite/dot/print_declaration.php
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `-l`, `--files-with-matches`
> Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
> file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The
> scanning will stop on the first  match.   (`-l`  is  specified  by
> POSIX.)

from [the manual of the GNU implementation of `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/General-Output-Control.html#index-names-of-matching-files). As noted above `-l` (`l` for *list*) is standard and portable, `--files-with-matches` (and long options in general) is a GNU extension.

Comment: I tried that, but must be putting it in the wrong place. grep -i-r --files-with-matches essay_ "shoppermarketexpo"
grep: invalid option -- -
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Comment: Never mind; I tried -l instead and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `-l` (el) or `--files-with-matches` command line switch(es)

> Suppress normal output; instead print
>   the  name  of  each  input
>                 file  from  which  output would normally have been
>   printed.  The
>                 scanning will stop on the first  match.   (-l  is  specified by POSIX.)